# I wish to place an image stored in the clipboard to a specific location on an excel spreadhseet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am using Microsoft project as the source of the image and wanting to paste to a specific location on a specified worksheet within an excel workbook.

```
Sub CreateImageAndPaste()

Dim EStart As String, LFin As String
EStart = ActiveProject.StatusDate - 30
LFin = Tsk.Finish + 30

'Create View, filter and table in MS Project and apply           

Application.PaneClose                 
MSProject.CalculateAll              
Application.EditCopyPicture Object:=False, ForPrinter:=0, SelectedRows:=0, FromDate:=EarliestStart, ToDate:=LFin, ScaleOption:=pjCopyPictureShowOptions, MaxImageHeight:=-1#, MaxImageWidth:=-1#, MeasurementUnits:=2

With xlsheet
    .Activate
    .Cells(1, 1) = t
    DoEvents
    .Paste
    DoEvents
End With
```

This snippet works perfectly in copying/pasting the desired image.  However, the image is pasted into cell A1 of the active worksheet.  I would like the Top-Left to be in cell A3.  How can this be done? I have researched the net and cannot find an example for an image which uses the EditCopy
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some additional time experimenting and doing more research and discovered that a range command can be added to the end of a Paste operation.

Final code that works for me is:

```
Application.PaneClose

MSProject.CalculateAll

Application.EditCopyPicture Object:=False, ForPrinter:=0, SelectedRows:=0, FromDate:=EarliestStart, ToDate:=LFin, ScaleOption:=pjCopyPictureShowOptions, MaxImageHeight:=-1#, MaxImageWidth:=-1#, MeasurementUnits:=2

ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set rng = xlsheet.Range("A3")
With xlsheet
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Target Task = " & t
    .Cells(2, 1) = "Iteration " & iteration
    DoEvents
End With

xlsheet.Paste Destination:=rng
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way, please:

```
 With xlsheet
    .Activate
    .Cells(1, 1) = t
    .Paste
    Application.Selection.ShapeRange.item(1).top = .Range("A3").top
    Application.Selection.ShapeRange.item(1).left = .Range("A3").left
 End With
```